# convert character string with no correct format to posixct

Tags: r, posixct

I have downloaded some climate reanalysis data, which took a lot of time to convert from grib, to cdf and finally now I've managed to make it work in R. The next issue I have is that time is a character vector, similar to the following:

```
tt =c(
    "20090101","20090101.25","20090101.5","20090101.75","20090102",
    "20090102.25","20090102.5","20090102.75","20090103","20090103.25",
    "20090103.5","20090103.75","20090104","20090104.25","20090104.5", 
    "20090104.75")
```

where the first four digits are the year, followed by month, then day, and finally fraction of the day: yyyymmdd...

How can I convert this to posixct time with a format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM?

I would try

as.POSIXct(tt,'%Y%m%d')

but this wont help here due to the day fraction.

The final result should be:

```
    tt
       [1] "2009-01-01 00:00"    "2009-01-01 06:00" "2009-01-01 12:00"  
"2009-01-01 18:00" "2009-01-02 00:00"
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Note: I can get half of the way with

```
as.Date(tt, "%Y%m%d")
```

but not sure what to do with the fraction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with:

```
tt=c("20090101"  ,  "20090101.25" ,"20090101.5" , "20090101.75" ,"20090102")
```

convert the date part and then extract the fractional part and add as a fraction of the day in seconds:

```
as.POSIXct(tt,format="%Y%m%d") + (as.numeric(tt) - as.integer(tt))*(60*60*24)
[1] "2009-01-01 00:00:00 GMT" "2009-01-01 06:00:00 GMT"
[3] "2009-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "2009-01-01 18:00:00 GMT"
[5] "2009-01-02 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: So in fact with `format="%Y%m%d"` you tell R to bring only the frist 3 "elements" of the input and ignore the rest. Am I right?

Comment: I think so, and `as.POSIXct("20010102!^£%!",format="%Y%m%d")` seems to agree.